# Sage: Drawing circles/horocycles in hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, sage

I'm trying to visualize some horocylces in the hyperbolic plane, and I usually use Sage to do math stuff, but when I read the [documentation reference](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/hyperbolic_geometry/index.html) for the hyperbolic geometry. I did not find a way to even draw a circle in the hyperbolic plane. I don't know if there is some package somewhere that can do this for me, or if I just need to write the code to do it. Alternatively, if anyone knows of a program that has horocycles and can act the modular group on horocycles that would also be great. Any help is appreciated.